# How to find Windows Service bus Log information

Tags: servicebus

How to find windows service bus log information along with message size like when message is received into queue.

Answer (score 0):

Logs for windows service bus can be find in the application logs in the **Windows Event Viewer application.**

My response is based on Microsoft documentation that can be find on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193001.aspx

**ATTENTION** My response is based on an assumption that you use Service Bus for Windows Server